# Unable to recover my Props

Tags: reactjs

**Solution :**
To solve this you should update your code in componentWillMount to this.getClients.call(this) which will call your function with a context of your react component so this.setState will be a valid method and will correctly update the state of the app.

---

Hello,

In my component i would like to retrieve some data from my api , and put it on the state. After that i transfer this state to my "info" component props.
[My image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdmUc.png)

In my info component i would like to show my data.

in the react dev tools , i see my data in info props but ...
[my image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z4Rym.png)

... in my console my props are the same for the begining.

ps: no photo allowed for the newbies who have at least 10 reputation ...

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: You can write code :)

Comment: Because i dont have at least 10 reputations i'm Restricted
I update my post
@DeividasKaržinauskas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your react app is not rerendering correctly. The problem is that you are calling `this` in the context of `.getClients()` function which has it's own context separate from react component.

To solve this you should update your code in `componentWillMount` to `this.getClients.call(this)` which will call your function with a context of your react component so `this.setState` will be a valid method and will correctly update the state of the app.

Comment: thanks for your answer !
it doesnt work :( 
in the react dev tools i see in my info component, he have the data in my props, but i cannot see in my console.log the data :(

Comment: When i set the state for the first time, can i put =   " this.state = . { clients : null } " when i want to store a object in this.state.clents ?

Comment: Yes, you can. But you can do this only in a constructor.

Comment: If it's gonna be an array of data, you may want to inutialize it into an empty array '[]'.

Comment: [screen1](http://imgur.com/L0GBFq8) 
this my data i received from my api , According to you how i can be for store my data in the state . for after using in my info component ?
[screen2](http://imgur.com/a/k2sdM)